# How to query two tables with distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a query that selects from table a and then from table b, but only returns data from table b that did not match an ID in table a. I'm currently using the union function but not sure where to go from here.

Table 1:

```
ID
---
1
2
```

Table 2:

```
ID
---
1
2
```

Query

```
Select
ID
1
2
From Table_1
Union
Select
ID
1
2
From Table_2
```

Thanks in advance!

I have tried using select distinct and except with no success.

Comment: So if table A has ids 1 and 2, and table B has ids 1, 2, and 3, you only want 3 in the result? or you want everything from A and B but without duplicates?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but I think you'll need to join table a and b to find out what is in b that isn't in a.

```
SELECT * FROM Table_1
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT B.*
    FROM Table_2 B
    LEFT JOIN Table_1 A
        ON B.ID = A.ID
    WHERE A.ID IS NULL
)
```

The nested query will select only the records from Table_2 that didn't have a corresponding record in Table_1.